# Struggling with Pagination links called from functions

Tags: php, database, pagination

HI I am developing pagination and would want to reference the links using functions. However I only get the "Previous" button if applied as a function and get the code correct when I manually type them in. Please notify me if you want me to send the entire code.

```
function pagelinks(){
    global $g,$CurrentPage,$Totalpages,$next,$previous;
    echo '<div id='.$g.'></div>';
    if($CurrentPage != 1){
        $previous = $CurrentPage - 1;
        echo '<a href = "?'.$g.'='.$previous.'">Back</a>';
    }

    if($CurrentPage != $Totalpages) {
        $next = $CurrentPage + 1;
        echo '<a class="pagination" href = "?'.$g.'='.$next.'">Next</a> ';

    }

    echo '</div>';
    $pageLinks =  array($previous,$next);
   return $pageLinks;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the best tutorial for pagination script i have ever used in my projects.

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/09/pagination-with-jquery-mysql-and-php.html

Answer (score 0):

I made another version of your function:

```
function pagelinks($g, $currentPage, $totalPages, &$next = null, &$previous = null)
{
    $out = '<div id='.$g.'></div>';
    if ($currentPage > 1) {
        $previous = $currentPage - 1;
        $out .= '<a href = "?'.$g.'='.$previous.'">Back</a>';
    }
    if ($currentPage < $totalPages) {
        $next = $currentPage + 1;
        $out .= '<a class="pagination" href = "?'.$g.'='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
    }
    $out .= '</div>';
    return $out;
}

echo pagelinks('page', 2, 5);

// if you need $next and $previous 
// just pass variables to function and use after function call
echo pagelinks('page', 2, 5, $next, $previous);

echo $next;
echo $previous;
```

I've tried to improve a few things.

1. No need for globals. Parameters must be passed to function. This makes sure every value is set.
2. No echo in function. Instead links will get returned.
3. $previous and $next can be passed as reference to function.
4. Changed conditions: $currentPage > 1 and $currentPage < $totalPages